# How to save data from Windows dialog box

Tags: windows-10

Some Windows software displays data in a dialog box without providing any way to save it. This is very frustrating. If there's not a lot of data, I can save a display image of the box and then run OCR on it to extract the data. The result is usually pretty good, but can have OCR errors, and sometimes the box has ellipses ("...") that truncate long values. If the box requires scrolling to see all the data, I can make multiple display images and OCR all of them. But if there's a lot of data, that becomes an unwieldy task. Here are some examples of the problem:

[image]
Display image of dialog box for Windows > MSconfig > Services

[image]
Display image of dialog box for Windows > Task Manager > Processes

[image]
Display image of dialog box for Windows > Resource Monitor > Overview

[image]
Display image of dialog box for Windows > Device Manager

[image]
Display image of dialog box for Windows > MSinfo32 > Software > Services

[image]
Display image of dialog box for Office > Outlook > View Mailbox Size

Two other examples are the list of programs in the Windows Control Panel and the list of programs in Windows > Settings > Apps

Obviously, all of these data have to be sitting somewhere, and Microsoft is allowing me to view them, but not to keep my own record of their values at a particular time. Where can I access the data?

Comment: Some data is stored but most is live data pulled when you open the app. Screenshots are your best bet.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they're stored or live, the data exist as text and numbers, from which the dialog boxes are made. There has to be a way to access the data behind the dialog boxes. I explained in the question the problems with using the display images: OCR errors, truncated values, and tediousness of large numbers of scrolled images.

Comment: I can't be the only one who wants to save this kind of data. Doesn't anyone here know how to do it?